# ¿Como solucionar problema de base_url() en mi proyecto con codeigniter?

Tags: php

Saludos. Estoy usando en framework de codeignite todo me corre bien con el base_url(), el problema es que cuando ingreso desde otro dispositivo en red si bien accede a la ventana principal no accede a los controladores!!! ni a nada que use base_url().
esta es mi configuración $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Alumbrado/';

En mi vista lo uso así 
`<form method="post" action="<?php base_url()?>cindex/login">
        <input type="txt" name="name" >
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>`

Y en mi computador corre normal el problema es cuando accedo desde otra maquina en red

Me conecto al servidor con la ip 192.168.10.5  **http://192.168.10.5/Alumbrado/**
y carga normal pero cuando envió el formulario me sale un error que dise que no tengo acceso ala dirección **//localhost/Alumbrado/** como veran al usar  base_url() como tiene el valor de **//localhost/Alumbrado/** lo cual hace que busque esa url en mi maquina cliente lo cual causa el error. y eso sucede donde pie el base_url(). y este proyecto tiene que funcionar en red !! y no se que puedo hacer para que no ocurra eso, gracias de antemano !!!!

Comment: Cambia tu configuracion `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Alumbrado/';` por `$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.10.5/Alumbrado/';` asi tu direccion base apuntará a la direccion ip del servidor en que está corriendo codeigniter

Comment: ok pero como esta en el localhost cuando lo remplazo  por 'http://192.168.10.5/Alumbrado/ me sale error  !!

Comment: Estas usando urls amigables en tu proyecto? si no es asi deberias ingresar a tus controladores mediante el index.php de tu proyecto.

Comment: osea me dices que no use el base_url()¡

Comment: No, me refiero a que si no tienes un htacces en tu proyecto para hacer urls amigables, deberías acceder a tus controladores de la forma normal, es decir: 
`http://192.168.10.5/Alumbrado/index.php/miControlador/miFuncion` suponiendo que tu proyecto se llama Alumbrado

Comment: tengo el .htacces y el proyecto y corre bien sin el index en mi servidor que es mi laptop, pero el problema es cuando accedo desde otra maquina en red al toparse con base_url() meda el error, no se que poner envés de base_url()  cuando lo quito y remplazo con ./ o ../ etc de acuerdo donde esta va bien

Comment: Si no te funciona colocando la ip de la maquina que hace de servidor, puede ser por el firewall de la maquina, intenta bajando el firewall

Comment: Agregale  echo a tu instruccion **<?php echo base_url();?>**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo que pasa es que localhost solo existe en tu ordenador, por eso es localhost, desde otros ordenadores y telefonos no puedes usar localhost porque dicha url no existe usa mejor lo siguiente, eso lo uso yo tambien y me funciona perfecto:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Alumbrado/'
```

**$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]**

esto funciona para capturar el nombre del servidor(dominio) en el que estas actualmente

Comment: ok gracias ahora si funciona !!!!! llevaba intentando ya mucho con $host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$url= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $host . $url; y nada, sino que me llevaba la url.

Comment: Hahaha, si yo tambien al principio hize los mismos intentos que tu, haha. Y por cierto no hay de que