# Problemas con css, js y direccionamiento al pasar al servidor con codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter, servidor

Hace un tiempo estoy trabajando en un proyecto que he desarrollado en Codeigniter 3.x donde realizo las típicas acciones de CRUD, además del llamado a JOBS en SQL Server.

Al probar el servicio de forma local, no presenta ningún inconveniente, todo funciona súper bien, carga todos los .css y .js, genera correctamente el direccionamiento, y todo genial.

Para realizar le direccionamiento, lo he realizado mediante el helper('url') el cual me permite utilizar base_url

cada llamada, ya sea CSS, js, u otras páginas las he realizado con ese helper.

Hasta ahí todo bien... El problema surge cuando traslado mi proyecto al servidor. Al ejecutarlo de forma local (en el servidor), funciona sin problemas. Pero necesito que otros usuarios se conecten a él y realicen sus operaciones.

al momento de ingresar desde otra computadora a la dirección de ese servidor la página carga, pero sin .css, ni .js, ni redirige...

Coloco un ejemplo de como estoy llamando a cada .css en la vista:

```
  <head>
    <title>Finanzas</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css');?>"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">  <!-- este funciona bien, pues no es con base_url -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url('imagenes/favicon.ico');?>" />
  </head>
```

---

Mi base_url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'servidor:4002/codeigniter/';
```

Naturalmente de este código solo es capaz de cargar el elemento que está siendo llamado sin el base_url.

Al ver mediante "view source code" del navegador, presiono click en el elemento llamado, y no me abre de inmediato el .css, debo copiar el enlace, pegarlo en el navegador y presionar enter.

¿alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano por el tiempo y la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el resultado final del head? Facilitaría detectr el posible problema

Comment: el base_url puedes dejarlo vacio

Answer (score 3):

El servidor está en la misma red por lo tanto puedo acceder mediante la dirección:

servidor/proyecto

---

De todos modos acabo de encontrar la solución a mi problema:

Esta solución la encontré en este foro. Había investigado bastante pero justo cuando publiqué la pregunta, encontré la respuesta...

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93691/62513 GRACIAS Risa__B (no pude etiquetarte)

el en respuesta a otro usuario publicó:

> lo que pasa es que localhost solo existe en tu ordenador, por eso es
>   localhost, desde otros ordenadores y telefonos no puedes usar
>   localhost porque dicha url no existe usa mejor lo siguiente, eso lo
>   uso yo tambien y me funciona perfecto:

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Alumbrado/'
    $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

> esto funciona para capturar el nombre del servidor(dominio) en el que
>   estas actualmente

---

CON ELLO FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE!

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a tu web qué url usas? En teoría debes tener un dominio con el que accedes tipo "http://www.midominio.es". Pues es esta url la que debes colocar en base_url:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.midominio.es";
```

Comment: El servidor está en la misma red por lo tanto puedo acceder mediante la dirección:

servidor/proyecto

De todos modos, 

Muchas gracias JoseFrancisco Dominguez Palac!...